# wordpress the_content not working on page template

Tags: wordpress, templates

i have a WordPress template page, which shows header, footer and sidebar, but the content not showing up anyone can help?

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Template 2
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="main_right" style="float:right;">
    <?php get_sidebar(1); ?>                        
 </div> 
<div style="float:left">    

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php echo the_content();?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't think you need the "echo" - the_content() echoes the content automatically.  Does it work if you remove it?

Comment: i also tried with removing echo but no effect

Comment: hmm; it looks ok other than that.  does your page have content?  if you switch to another template does it appear?

Answer (score 3):

Is this within your wordpress loop? It has to be in order for the_content to work.

Also, you don't need to echo the function, just place it in your file like so…

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Also, why would you want to wrap the content in `<p>` tags? Wordpress does this for you automatically. If you want to wrap it something a `<div>` would be much better, probably with a class or id for css use.

Have you had a look at the wordpress codex? - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content